# Concluding that a linear operator on a Hilbert space is invertible

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

**Setting:**

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with two inner products, $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ and $[\cdot, \cdot]$, and $S:H\to H$ be a bounded linear operator such that for all $x,y\in H$, we have $\langle Sx,y \rangle = [x,y]$.  Suppose further that the two inner products induce norms which are equivalent.

---

Under these hypotheses, can we conclude that $S$ is a bijection with bounded inverse?

Comment: Hellinger-Toeplitz theorem implies that $S$ is bounded, Lax-Milgram thm then implies that $S$ is bijective (+ bounded & bijective implies that the inverse in bounded, say by open mapping theorem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We get the lower bound from
$$\|Sx\|\,\|x\|\ge   \langle Sx,x\rangle  =  [x,x] \ge c\langle x,x\rangle  = c\|x\|^2 \tag1$$ 
where $\|\cdot \|^2 = \langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle $.
Hence, the range of $S$ is closed. If $S$ is not surjective, there is a nonzero $y $ such that $\langle Sx,y\rangle =0$ for all $x$. But then $\langle Sy,y\rangle =0$, which implies $y=0$ by (1).

Comment: Thanks for the direct argument.  :)