# A criterion for invertibility of a bounded linear map

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $T$ be a bounded linear operator from the Hilbert space $H_1$ to a Hilbert space $H_2$. Suppose there exists $\delta>0$ such that 
$$
\langle T^{*}Tx,x\rangle\ge \delta \|x\|^2 
$$
for all $x\in H_1$, and
$$
\langle TT^{*}y,y\rangle\ge \delta \|y\|^2 
$$
for all $y \in H_2$. Then it is easily seen that $T$ and $T^{*}$ are injective.

My goal is to show that $T$ must be invertible, and, by the Open Mapping Theorem, it suffices to show that it is bijective. But I need some help to show that it is surjective (injectivity of $T^{*}$ only implies that the range of $T$ is dense in $H_2$). Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: see the answer to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828288/concluding-that-a-linear-operator-on-a-hilbert-space-is-invertible?rq=1 I think it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image of $T$ is also closed: Take $T(x_k)\rightarrow y_0 \in H_2$.  Then $T(x_k)$ is Cauchy.  Since $T$ is bounded below, the sequence $x_k$ is also Cauchy. So $x_k\rightarrow x_0$.  So $T(x_0)=y_0$.